# Sorting a linked list in an ascending way

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to write a function that inserts numbers(from the user)to nodes (1 number for each node) and then sorts them in an ascending way.
I wrote this function:

```
void insertnode(struct n_node *head)
{
    struct n_node *temp = head;
    int number;
    printf("Please insert a number to the node\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    while (number != SENTRY)
    {
        while ((temp->next != NULL) && (temp->next->num < number))
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        struct n_node *addNode = (struct n_node*)malloc(sizeof(struct n_node));
        addNode->num = number;
        if (temp->next == NULL && number < temp->num)
        {
            addNode->next = temp;
            head = addNode;
        }
        else
        {
            addNode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = addNode;
        }
        temp = head;
        scanf("%d", &number);
    }
    options();
}
```

It compiles but right after I insert the first number is stops, gives me a break message and points on this line:

```
while ((temp->next != NULL) && (temp->next->num < number))
```

nothing appears on the error list, any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Also, always check for `malloc()` success

Comment: note that you can not update to the beginning of list by the new node.

Answer (score 2):

In your algorithm, you are not testing the special cases in the correct order:

- if the list is empty, `head` is `NULL` and the test `temp->next != NULL` invokes undefined behaviour.
- if the number is smaller than the number in the first node, there is no need to try and iterate over the list, the node needs to be inserted at the head.

You should first allocate the new node and check the special cases with a single test:

```
 struct n_node *addNode = malloc(sizeof(struct n_node));
 addNode->num = number;

 if (head == NULL || number < head->num) {
     addNode->next = head;
     head = addNode;
 }
```

Otherwise, your iteration loop is correct and the node is to be inserted after `temp` when you reach the false condition:

```
    while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->num < number) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    addNode->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = addNode;
```

The loop becomes much simpler:

```
void insertnode(struct n_node **headp) {
    struct n_node *head = *headp;
    int number;
    printf("Please insert a number to the node\n");

    while (scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number != SENTRY) {
        struct n_node *addNode = malloc(sizeof(struct n_node));
        if (addNode == NULL) {
            printf("out of memory\n");
            return;
        }
        addNode->num = number;

        if (head == NULL || number < head->num) {
            addNode->next = head;
            *headp = head = addNode;
        } else {
            struct n_node *temp = head;
            while (temp->next != NULL && temp->next->num < number) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            addNode->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = addNode;
        }
    }
    options(); // head is not passed to the function?
}
```

Also note the change in API to allow the function to update the list head in the caller's scope, the change to stop scanning for numbers upon end of file or a non number input in addition to a magic number.

Comment: Your 'temp' is not declared.

Comment: Also the function does not work because when I try to enter a number to the node it gets two numbers and then it stops again.

Comment: @Jokerah: what are you typing exactly ?

Comment: a number, for example I enter 1 and then it is suppose to ask me again to enter a number but it doesnt and it lets me enter 2 number for example 1 *I press enter* and then 2, then it crashes.